# Running an OpenVPN server in Docker on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: vpn, docker, openvpn, containers, ubuntu-20.04

I'd like to run an OpenVPN server on my Ubuntu 20.04 server. There are plenty step-by-step guides as to how to do so (like [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-20-04-lts-set-up-openvpn-server-in-5-minutes/) or [there](https://markontech.com/sysadmin/setup-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu/)), this seems fairly straightforward process.

However instead of running the VPN server 'directly' on the server, I'd prefer to run it in a Docker container.

Is this possible, and is there a guideline on how to set this up, or perhaps some pointers in the right direction?

Comment: There are 2415 openvpn containers on the Docker hub. Why don't you try some of them?

Answer (score 0):

As Gerald has answered, here is one example that can install the latest OpenVPN inside a docker on Ubuntu 22.04 - but as it indicated other linux distribution and version will work as well.

https://adamtheautomator.com/openvpn-in-docker/